# How to determine whether a circle collider goes through an edge collider trigger, or turns back during collision?

Tags: c#, triggers, unity-game-engine

Working in Unity 4.3, 2D mode and C#. I have a player controlled circle with a circle collider and a static edge collider with irregular shapes. The edge collider is in trigger mode.

The circle is supposed to react in a certain way once it has completely passed through the edge collider, but not if it collides with it, and turns back to the same direction it came from. The circle should be able to spin randomly and to cross the edge collider from any direction or angle and at any speed.

I'm trying to use OnTriggerExit2D, but I haven't been able to check if the circle goes through or turns back, because OnTriggerExit2D is launched in both occasions. Here's a picture to clarify:

[image: Circle Edge]

Thanks in advance, this has been driving me nuts for the past few days.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could record the object's position in `OnTriggerEnter2D`, and then compare it to current position in `OnTriggerExit2D`. Then use `Physics2D.Linecast` to determine whether there's a collider between those points - if yes, then you passed through. Note that this might not work reliably if your edge collider shape is complex and the object moves generally along the edge rather than across it.

Comment: Kiitti Arttu, didn't know about this linecast. My game is a physics puzzle with changing gravity, and the edge collider works as a continuos collider for ground - so it's quite complex. I have a working MacGyver solution for this now, I'll post it soon.